# What's the most efficient inter-process communication method for a high-bandwidth data stream on a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, ipc

I have a C++ program (running under MacOS/X) that generates a high-bandwidth stream of data (about 27 megabytes per second).  A second C++ program receives that data and processes it in (soft) real time.  Low latency and high reliability are both goals for this system.  Due to circumstances beyond my control, the two processes need to be kept separate -- that is, I can't convert them into two threads within the same process.

Currently I'm using UDP packets (sent by process A to a UDP port on 127.0.0.1 that process B is listening on) to implement this data transfer, and that more-or-less-kind-of-works (modulo the occasional dropped packet), but I'm wondering if there isn't a more efficient/appropriate mechanism for this use case.  Would a Unix pipe() be significantly more efficient or reliable?  Or should I write the data to a mmap()'d shared memory region, and use a pipe/socket/semaphore/etc to synchronize the two processes' writes and reads?  Or is UDP-over-the-loopback-device already efficient enough that there is little benefit to be gained by switching over to another method?

Comment: (As a hint, whenever you're doing UDP/TCP over a loopback socket, a standard UNIX file-ish socket should provide better performance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can't beat shared memory if you can manage the synchronization. Single copy in memory, no other movement. Your only "slow" point will be any fighting over who can do what, and where.

Comment: I second this. I have successfully written a program that can multiplex a video stream of over 100MB/s to multiple downstream reader processes using shared memory on OS X. It runs happily on an old 2011 MacBook with no trouble.